# Why is my 2D FFT convolution displacing the result?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fft

I am trying to solve a simple heat equation via FFT convolution with a 3x3 gaussian kernel.
To keep things simple, I am using a very small domain (4 by 5 matrix). Here's the MWE:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft2, ifft2

gaussian_ker = np.array([[1, 2, 1], [2, 4, 2], [1, 2, 1],])/16
domain = np.zeros((4, 5))
domain[1,1] = 1 # initial condition

def diffusion(ker, D):
    x = fft2(ker, s=D.shape)
    y = fft2(D)
    return np.real(ifft2(x*y))

print( np.round(diffusion(gaussian, domain),4) )
```

Initially, the matrix is:

```
0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
```

And after applying my function, I get:

```
0.      0.      0.      0.      0.
0.      0.0625  0.125   0.0625  0.
0.      0.125   0.25    0.125   0.
0.      0.0625  0.125   0.0625  0.
```

The expected result (also what `scipy.convolve` gives) would be:

```
0.0625  0.125   0.0625  0.      0.
0.125   0.25    0.125   0.      0.
0.0625  0.125   0.0625  0.      0.
0.      0.      0.      0.      0.
```

Why is this "displacement" along the diagonal happening?

Comment: Yes, it works... But this leads to another question: since the `s` parameter of `np.fft2` supposedly pads the input, how should I apply the shift if I wanna make use of `s`? I ask this because I tried shifting before asking the question and it didn't work... It only works if I do like you said in that answer, by manually padding then shifting. Applying `fftshift` and/or `ifftshift` to the domain doesn't work.

Comment: Indeed, you can’t rely on the `s` parameter in this case. You need the manual padding.